# Can't access pointer while navigating linked list

Tags: c, hash, linked-list

I'm making a simple hash table and a hash function. Each element of the table has a pointer to another node that is used by the insert function when a collision occurs. The problem is that when a collision occurs my code simply crashes when it's navigating the linked list. Here is the code (sorry if it's a little lengthy):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hash.h"
#define TAM 50

int funcaoHash(int chave, char nome[50]) //Hash function
{
    int i;
    int hash = chave;
    for(i = 0; nome[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        hash = hash + (int)nome[i];
    }
    hash = hash%TAM;
    return hash;
}

void insere(int chave, char nome[50], itemTabela* TabelaHash[TAM]) //Insert function
{
    int idx = funcaoHash(chave, nome);

    itemTabela* ItemAux = (itemTabela*)malloc(sizeof(itemTabela));
    itemTabela* ptrAux = NULL;
    ItemAux->chave = chave;
    strcpy(ItemAux->nome, nome);

    if(TabelaHash[idx] == NULL) //No collision occurred
        TabelaHash[idx] = ItemAux;

    //If there is a collision
    else
    {
        ptrAux = TabelaHash[idx]->ptr;

        //Here the code breaks
        while(ptrAux->ptr != NULL)
        {
            ptrAux = ptrAux->ptr;
        }
        ptrAux = ItemAux;
    }
}

void inicializaTabela(itemTabela* TabelaHash[TAM]) //Initialize tabl
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
        TabelaHash[i] = NULL;
}
```

Here is the node structure:

```
typedef struct itemTabela
{
    char nome[50];
    int chave;
    struct itemTabela* ptr;
}itemTabela;
```

And here is the main function:

```
int main()
{
    itemTabela *ptrTabela[TAM] = {};
    inicializaTabela(ptrTabela);
    insere(6, "Chico", ptrTabela);
    insere(6, "Chico", ptrTabela);
    return 0;
}
```

Am I accessing the pointers in the wrong way or doing some ilegal access? 
Thanks for your time!

Comment: "The problem is that when a collision occurs my code simply crashes when it's navigating the linked list."  -- what is the crash?  Did you use a debugger to try to figure this out yourself?

Comment: Yes! The debugger says that it can't access the memory of the next pointer.
Here are its exact words: "Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf045"

Comment: Which statement did that happen on? What pointer has that value?

Comment: It happens in the ptrAux = ptrAux->ptr statement.

Comment: [Hint] `int funcaoHash(int chave, char nome[50])`Start by making your hash value unsigned; you do not want overflow, and you *certainly* dont want negative results (which will be used as an index in your pointer array.) -->> `unsigned funcaoHash(unsigned chave, char *nome)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)
Initialization of `ItemAux` also requires `ptr` initialization. like `ItemAux->ptr = NULL;`

2)

```
    ptrAux = TabelaHash[idx]->ptr;

    //Here the code breaks
    while(ptrAux->ptr != NULL)
    {
        ptrAux = ptrAux->ptr;
    }
    ptrAux = ItemAux;
```

should be

```
    ptrAux = TabelaHash[idx];

    while(ptrAux->ptr != NULL)
    {
        ptrAux = ptrAux->ptr;
    }
    ptrAux->ptr = ItemAux;
```

Comment: If ordering is not important, you should insert it before, not behind.